# trigger - on change - stops after first action

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am attempting to have my trigger do multiple actions in my google sheet after an automated form from slack inputs a row into my sheet. The actions that I want it to do are:

1. insert todays date in a certain column
2. Fill formula down on column k
3. Fill formula down on column l
4. Fill formula down on column m

So far I am only getting the first behavior - Here is my code:

```
function setUpTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onEdit')
  .forSpreadsheet('1QOx3H-NsK52bojXv1J-bq-9jt2ZJKG8RaiiAdcDAx4w')
  .onChange()
  .create();
}

function onEdit() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on Sheet1 or not
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) { //checks that the cell being edited is in column A
var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //checks if the adjacent cell is empty or not?
nextCell.setValue(Utilities. formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5:00", "''MM-dd-yyyy"))
var lr = s.getLastRow();
var fillDownRange1 = s.getRange(2,11,lr-1);
var fillDownRange2 = s.getRange(2,12,lr-1);
var fillDownRange3 = s.getRange(2,13,lr-1);
s.getRange(K2).copyTo(fillDownRange1);
s.getRange(L2).copyTo(fillDownRange2);
s.getRange(M2).copyTo(fillDownRange3)
} }
}
```

How do I get the values to fill down from my formulas when new rows are added?
`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that I get two entries in my executions log with that kind of a trigger. The first is a simple trigger and the second is an installable trigger. And I also get inconsistent results. Sometimes the function I wrote works and sometimes the code keeps on running until it times out. Personally, I'd avoid doing such a thing. It's okay to create an onChange installable trigger but don't name it onEdit(e) because that's the default for a simple onEdit trigger. At first I thought it might be an interesting way to get e.range when using an onChange trigger but I think it would cause more problems than it's worth.

Comment: Thanks, but I dont know exactly what I am doing here and didnt know that could create a problem.  My code doesnt do anything after filling the date which is: nextCell.setValue(Utilities. formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5:00", "''MM-dd-yyyy"....  Ive copied and pasted from other tutorials around the web on how to copy down using the script app, but this doesnt seem to really do anything.  Does your code copy down on any formulas?

Comment: You didn't create a problem that I know of.  I think you should just rename it and try it again.